# How can I write text like "k times" below a mathematical equation?

Tags: equations

In writing a control proof, I need to type "k times" below the two products as shown in the code below. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

To prove: $\boxed{  [ \Phi(t) ]^k = \Phi(k t). }$

        Since $\Phi(t) = e^{A t}$, we find that
        $$
        [ \Phi(t) ]^k = \Phi(t) \Phi(t) \cdots \Phi(t) = e^{A t}  e^{A t} \cdot e^{A t} = e^{k A t}
        $$
        
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX Output]

Comment: I fully agree that it is "generally understood" when we write a research paper and we don't need to spell out "k times" with "underbrace".. However, for lecture notes, I like to add this for "pedagogy".. I am writing lecture notes for a control course that I teach to M. Tech engineering students, and I like to ensure that they understand in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `\underbrace` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

To prove: $\boxed{  [ \Phi(t) ]^k = \Phi(k t). }$

    Since $\Phi(t) = e^{A t}$, we find that
    \[ 
        [ \Phi(t) ]^k
        = \underbrace{ \Phi(t) \Phi(t) \cdots \Phi(t) }_{k \text{ times}}
        = \underbrace{ e^{A t}  e^{A t} \cdots e^{A t} \mathstrut }_{k \text{ times}}
        = e^{k A t}
    \]
        
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

A `\mathstrut` is placed to improve the spacing of the second brace.

Note that you should use `\[`...`\]` in LaTeX instead of the deprecated `$$`...`$$`. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/) for more information.

Comment: Amazing! It works very well. I will accept your answer after a day or two as moderators advised me to wait for other answers as well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am very comfortable using $$ .... $$ - I still use LaTeX 2e only.. I had no issues so far in MikTeX - thanks!

Comment: plante: I assume there is a similar "\overbrace" command in amsmath that works in a similar way.. I shall test it also, thanks!

Comment: plante: "\overbrace" also works well.. I guess we use "\underbrace" more commonly for derivations like this, thanks!   $$
  [ \Phi(t) ]^k = \overbrace{ \Phi(t) \Phi(t) \cdots \Phi(t) }^{k \text{ times}}=  \overbrace{e^{A t}  e^{A t} \cdot e^{A t} }^{k \  \text{times}} = e^{k A t} =
\Phi(k t)
 $$

Comment: @Dr.Sundar you should not be comfortable with `$$`, it is wrong and has never been supported LaTeX syntax, it is not even mentioned in the official LaTeX book. This has nothing to do with LaTeX2e/laTeX3, `$$` was not supported in LaTeX2.09 either.

Comment: David: OK, I will start typing in `\[`...`\]`  for display equations from now on..

Comment: Note that `\underbrace` isn't from `amsmath`. It's part of the LaTeX (and plain TeX) kernel.

Comment: campa: thanks for reminding, I have corrected the answer